# Joomla "404 category not found" error

Tags: php, joomla, http-status-code-404, categories

I've just upgraded a Joomla website to version 3.5.1 in order to support PHP 7.
This site is hosted on a server which ran PHP 5.3 till now. So far every version of Joomla worked fine.

But when I upgrade PHP to version 7, I encounter "404 category not found" errors on many links on the frontend, including menus. Actually all first level menu entries are OK but all second level menu entries and links in articles give errors. However I haven't seen any issue on the admin panel.

When I get back to PHP version 5.3, it's OK again.
I tried with PHP version 5.6 too and got the same error.

For developpement and tests purposes, I have a copy of the full site (a backup of files and data) at home : it worked before with PHP 5.6, and it's still working now with PHP 7.

I looked through the PHP configurations of my PC and the server. But I'm not skilled enough to see anything obvious that could help.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What happens when you set the error reporting in the configuration settings to the maximum? Do you see any errors?

Comment: The http server error log shows "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error" messages. There's not much information. How can I make it more verbose ? The Joomla error.log doesn't provide any usefull information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved : my web-hosting provider (OVH) introduced a specific php config file for mutualized hosting 2 years ago. Since my site was older the file was missing. Once this file is added with the right parameters (among them the PHP version) the links get back to normal again.